# Does locking in Java creates core affinity and hinders/discourages threads being scheduled on all cores

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, concurrency, locking

I have implemented a producer-consumer pattern to facilitate interaction between threads . But the contention of locking is only among producer threads and not between consumer and any of producer threads. Still the application works on maximum 50% of CPU usage with all threads being scheduled on a single core (it's Windows 10 OS, not any server OS). It almost behaves like a serial process where consumer thread is waiting for it's slice.

**Can thread-safe logging be kind of bottleneck** (because everything is logged to a single file in our web application) ?

*My intention is atleast consumer thread should be able get slice in parallel to producer threads.*

Comment: We cannot possibly answer this question without seeing your code.  Please try to make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.

Comment: will you remove downvote , if i add code (although it's my company's IP now)  ? I have seen similar questions without code snippet in stackoverflow.

Comment: If it's your company's IP then you need to create a standalone [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, that you can share with us.  Actually, taking the time to make a [mcve] will probably let you solve the problem on your own and learn something in the process.  This is why it is ALWAYS a good ideea to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Why speculate when you can test? The correct answer is to change your logger to avoid having to contend for a file or cached resource or use a ThreadLocal to isolate your logger and rerun your program and analyze the result yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive reply. The thing is I have already suggested this to my technical lead, a month ago. Atleast I got a Linux VM on friday (instead of my current workstation windows) , I am going to deploy the code today and do the performance test with Gatling( a scala based tool for performance testing).In the meanwhile of those long running tests ,will create a separate log file for my consumer thread. I am a contracted developer , if i am dedicating my time to a approach that is not yet approved , I need to have strong base.